# How to exit a stored procedure in PDW

Tags: stored-procedures, parallel-data-warehouse

I am working in PDW AU5.  I am writing a stored procedure that needs dynamic SQL (because of variable database names).  So, to prevent SQL injection, I am doing a simple test of the input parameter value to the stored procedure.  If the test fails, I want to exit the stored procedure.  Normally on SMP, I would do this with RETURN -1.  However, RETURN isn't allowed in stored procs on PDW.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the QUOTENAME function to escape the single quote character on the input string to stop the Dynamic SQL from injected.

```
DECLARE @userfield VARCHAR(255) = 'abc'' ;SELECT 1; '
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@UserField, '''')

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

See another post about how to prevent SQL Injection [how to prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809608/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap the code around an IF statement and in the section where it's supposed to be RETURN*ed* just make sure the IF condition isn't met and the whole code block is bypassed and onto the end of the stored procedure.

e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspDynamicSQL
( @UserField varchar(255) )
AS

IF CHARINDEX(@UserField) > 0 THEN
BEGIN

-- YOUR SQL CODE AS NORMAL

END;
```

It's not pretty but it works.