# Quotationmark problem with Knex and SQL-database

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to save a query to a database using Knex. But if this query I'm trying to save includes quotation marks I'm getting an error.

Here's an example of how the code might look like:

```
db.query(`INSERT INTO test.searches VALUES ('TestUser', 'testqueryname', ''SELECT * FROM table WHERE team='rocket'')`, info, () =>{}
```

Of course in the real case I'm not sending in hardcoded values but variables as strings.

Trying to save this gets me the error

> error: syntax error at or near "rocket"

Answer (score 1):

To start with looks like your code has javascript syntax error at least closing parenthesis is missing.

Secondly knex does not have `.query()` method (maybe you are using database driver directly?). You should probably be using `knex.raw()` even that query above could be easily written with normal `knex` methods.

If you are using knex.raw you can do quoting with `??` replacements and value bindings wit `?`.

If you are writing your code like in the question you have no advantage at all from using `knex` and you should be using database driver directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL, you need to [slash escape quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql):

```
db.query(`INSERT INTO test.searches VALUES ('TestUser', 'testqueryname', 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE team=\'rocket\'')`, info, () =>{}
```

If you are running PostgreSQL, you need to [double escape quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql):

```
db.query(`INSERT INTO test.searches VALUES ('TestUser', 'testqueryname', 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE team=''rocket''')`, info, () =>{}
```

Please consider using [parameterised SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688366/how-to-write-parameterized-sql-query-to-prevent-sql-injection) or at least appropriately escaping input to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will have a look at this!